# Ruby on Rails application could not be started

Tags: ruby-on-rails, passenger, dreamhost

I put my first Rails app online on Dreamhost, but I keep getting "Ruby on Rails application could not be started" ([you can see it directly](http://www.foto-fiori.com)).

Then running rake exiftool process seems to be killed by DH: sh: line 1: 10645 Killed
convert "/tmp/stream20090806-10125-x36lrj-0[0]" -resize "x150" -crop
"150x150+25+0" +repage "/tmp/stream20090806-10125-x36lrj-0,10125,0"
2>/dev/null

script/console works properly and gems seems to be installed. Apache logs say nothing (because I have a limited access to them).

The terminal output will explain everything better than a thousand words:

```
 Welcome to castiglia.dreamhost.com

[castiglia]$ cd ~/foto-fiori.com
[castiglia]$ rake
(in /mnt/local/home/collimarco/foto-fiori.com)
/usr/bin/ruby1.8 -Ilib:test "/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.3/lib/rake/rake_test_loader.rb" "test/unit/user_test.rb" "test/unit/comment_test.rb" "test/unit/helpers/password_resets_helper_test.rb" "test/unit/helpers/classifications_helper_test.rb" "test/unit/helpers/comments_helper_test.rb" "test/unit/helpers/photos_helper_test.rb" "test/unit/helpers/info_helper_test.rb" "test/unit/classification_test.rb" "test/unit/photo_test.rb" "test/unit/notifier_test.rb" 
Loaded suite /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.3/lib/rake/rake_test_loader
Started
.....
Finished in 0.130391 seconds.

5 tests, 5 assertions, 0 failures, 0 errors
/usr/bin/ruby1.8 -Ilib:test "/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.3/lib/rake/rake_test_loader.rb" "test/functional/comments_controller_test.rb" "test/functional/classifications_controller_test.rb" "test/functional/photos_controller_test.rb" "test/functional/info_controller_test.rb" "test/functional/password_resets_controller_test.rb" 
Loaded suite /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.3/lib/rake/rake_test_loader
Started
....sh: line 1: 10645 Killed                  convert "/tmp/stream20090806-10125-x36lrj-0[0]" -resize "x150" -crop "150x150+25+0" +repage "/tmp/stream20090806-10125-x36lrj-0,10125,0" 2>/dev/null
F......
Finished in 18.62476 seconds.

  1) Failure:
test_should_create_photo(PhotosControllerTest) [/test/functional/photos_controller_test.rb:21]:
"Photo.count" didn't change by 1.
 expected but was
.

11 tests, 13 assertions, 1 failures, 0 errors
/usr/bin/ruby1.8 -Ilib:test "/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.3/lib/rake/rake_test_loader.rb"  
Errors running test:functionals!
[castiglia]$ script/console production
Loading production environment (Rails 2.3.3)
>> User.count
=> 7
>> exit
[castiglia]$ rake gems:install
(in /mnt/local/home/collimarco/foto-fiori.com)
[castiglia]$ rake gems
(in /mnt/local/home/collimarco/foto-fiori.com)
 - [I] mysql 
 - [I] mini_exiftool 

I = Installed
F = Frozen
R = Framework (loaded before rails starts)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have all the correct versions of your Gems installed on the Dreamhost server? I had a similar error with my Rails 2.3 app, because Dreamhost only had Rails 2.2 installed.

Solved the problems by freezing the Rails to 2.3 in my app.